# Get wordpress authors in order by the number of custom posts published

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.8.1, I have a list of authors who post in custom posts `song` and `poem`. With the below code I am getting the list of authors who posted in the both or either in one custom post.

```
 $authors = get_users(array(
        'who' => 'authors',
        'has_published_posts' => array('song','poem'),
        'orderby' => 'post_count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'number' => '15'
 ));
```

Below code is listing all the authors with their post counts:

```
foreach ($authors as $user) {
   $name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
   $songs = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "song");
   $poems = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "poem");
   echo $name.' has '. $songs .' songs, and '. $poems .' poems;
}
```

With `'orderby' => 'post_count'` in the arguments, I expected the authors list with highest combined custom posts count displayed first, however it is showing randomly with no order, neither by `post_counts` nor `ID`.

How can I order the authors with most combined total posts?

Comment: Just to confirm - before your for loop, you're saying this query does not order by post_counts ? If you run this query directly in your DB is the result different ?

Comment: Not tested in DB directly.

Comment: I just tried the same request with *get_users()* and these parameters with WordPress 5.8.1 and it worked perfectly. I checked how the query is prepared in source code: it is a huge mess but the options you pass are correctly taken into account.

Answer (score 5):

Try below code.

```
$authors = get_users(array(
    'who' => 'authors',
    'has_published_posts' => array('song','poem'),
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => '15'
));
```

Create one `array` and count total poem + songs

```
$author_posts = array();

foreach ($authors as $user) {
    $name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
    $songs = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "song");
    $poems = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "poem");
    $author_posts[] = array(
        'total' => $songs+$poems,
        'label' => $name.' has '. $songs .' songs, and '. $poems .' poems'
    );
}
```

now use `usort to sort an array by total.

```
usort($author_posts, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['total']==$b['total']) return 0;
    return $a['total'] < $b['total']?1:-1;
});
```

print the output.

```
foreach ( $author_posts as $key => $author_post ) {
    echo $author_post['label']."</br>";
}
```

**Complete code.**

```
$authors = get_users(array(
    'who' => 'authors',
    'has_published_posts' => array('song','poem'),
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => '15'
));

$author_posts = array();

foreach ($authors as $user) {
    $name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
    $songs = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "song");
    $poems = count_user_posts($user->ID, $post_type = "poem");
    $author_posts[] = array(
        'total' => $songs+$poems,
        'label' => $name.' has '. $songs .' songs, and '. $poems .' poems'
    );
}

usort($author_posts, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['total']==$b['total']) return 0;
    return $a['total'] < $b['total']?1:-1;
}); 

foreach ( $author_posts as $key => $author_post ) {
    echo $author_post['label']."</br>";
}
```

**Tested and works.**

Answer (score 1):

First, the *orderby* argument of function *get_users()* works with *post_count* but counts all post types (here, it is counting *poem*, *song* and the others types like *post* or *page*).

If you want to order your results by specific custom post types, I would recommend to use the [wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) class to design your own request. This allows you to get the exact desired results with one single request and no need to use a *foreach* to sort your results after.

I tried this way and it worked:

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT
        $wpdb->users.ID AS author_id,
        $wpdb->users.display_name AS author_name,
        COUNT($wpdb->posts.ID) AS published_songs_and_poems,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'song' THEN $wpdb->posts.ID ELSE NULL END) as published_songs,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'poem' THEN $wpdb->posts.ID ELSE NULL END) as published_poems
    FROM $wpdb->users
    JOIN $wpdb->posts
        ON $wpdb->posts.post_author = $wpdb->users.ID
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN('song', 'poem') AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY author_id
    ORDER BY published_songs_and_poems DESC"
);
```

This request return an object with results grouped by author and order by total amount of published songs and poems.

You can use this object as you already did. Something like this :

```
array_walk($authors, function($author) {
    echo $author->author_name." has published ".$author->published_songs." song(s) and ".$author->published_poems." poem(s).<br/>";
});
```

I edited this answer because the first version focused on how to return the results order by total *post_count*. This was clarified when commented by @theKing.

Comment: There are other custom post types than songs and poems in my WP; but here I want to sort authors from combined songs & poems count only.

Comment: Wouldn't this perform a query to get all the authors, and then another query for every author in the list?

Comment: Thank you for clarification, @theKing. I just edited my answer. As Healyhatman mentioned, there is a risk of multiple DB requests. That is why a custom request seems to be the best approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error inside your `foreach` block, it might be what's causing the issue. Use this instead:

```
foreach ($authors as $user) {
   $name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
   $songs = count_user_posts($user->ID, "songs");
   echo $name.' has '. $songs .' songs ';
}
```

In short, replace the `$post_type = "songs"` with simply `"songs"`. See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/) for details on accepted parameters.

**EDIT**: I misunderstood the question. Looking at your query, everything is as it should be so I would look elsewhere for the source of the problem. Do you have plugins or filters that might change the query? Can you reproduce your query directly in the database and does it work there? (to rule out table or index corruption)

Comment: It did not helped. My issues is to order the authors by their post count in DESC order. 
With the current code, I am getting the each individuals authors post count echoed.

Comment: You're right, I completely missed the point of your question. Is the post count accurate? Are you able to make the same query directly on the database and get correct results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php wp_list_authors( $args ); ?> 



<?php $args = array(
'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
'orderby'       => 'post_count', 
'order'         => 'DESC', 
'number'        => null,
'optioncount'   => false, 
'exclude_admin' => true, 
'show_fullname' => false,
'hide_empty'    => true,
'echo'          => true,
'style'         => 'list',
'html'          => true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this using the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin.

As others have suggested, there are a few reasons this may not be working the way you expect.  One is that your query is being altered by another plugin.  Another is that the query is fine but the post_count is not what you expect.  To get to the bottom of things you need to see exactly what's going on with your query.

Install and activate the Query Monitor plugin.  Load the page that runs your query then open the query monitor output.  Look under queries and scroll down to find yours.  That will show you the query that Wordpress is running.  Check it and make sure it is what you expect.

If the query has been altered then start deactivating plugins until you find the culprit.

If the query is correct then copy it, go to your database (phpmyadmin or whatever you use) and run it yourself.  You will see the results directly from the database and it should be obvious why the order of records is not what you expect.